# nested form & update_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

i am having trouble updating data in a multi-level nested form.  i use partials to include all the fields for both the create & update views, and i do NOT have a problem with creating. only with updating.

essentially the structure (simplified) is:

```
user has_one profile
profile has_many addresses

form_for @user do |u|
  u.fields_for :profile do |p|
    p.fields_for :addresses do |a|
```

like i said, creating the user, profile, and addresses works fine.  only until i attempt to update do i find problems.  i don't receive an error, it actually shows it was successfully updated.  and it actually does properly update the user & profile fields, just not the address fields.

here are the params for the update from the stack trace. (again, summarized & formatted)

```
Parameters: {"controller"=>"profiles", "action"=>"update", "_method"=>"put", "id"=>"1", 
  "user"=>{"login" => "username",
    "profile_attributes"=>{"first_name"=>"Admin",
      "addresses_attributes"=>{
        "0"=>{"address"=>"123 Address Ave.", "city"=>"Cityville", "state"=>"CA"}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

all of the documentation i can find only shows 1 nested form, so i am not sure if i am using update_attributes properly for more than 1 level deep.

any thoughts?

Comment: Are you using the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method?

Comment: yes i am.  in my profile model i have   accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, :allow_destroy => true

Comment: Having the exact same problem.  I'm using rails v3.0.3 and ruby 1.9.2p0.   I'm interested if anyone using 2 or more levels of nesting ISN'T having this problem.

Comment: Further detail, grandchildren can be added/removed using << and .delete() in IRB just fine.  It seems to be related to #update_attributes

Comment: I created a sample app to highlight the problem/bug report.  Of course it works fine in the sample app, so I'm definitely doing something wrong.

Comment: If you created the records already, and you are performing an update, then there should be an id attribute that is getting passed along with your addresses. This tells ActiveRecord which existing record in the database to update with the attributes submitted. From the parameters I see here, it doesn't look like AR thinks you're doing an update to an existing record at all. In the process of summarizing and formatting, did you remove the 'id' attributes?

Comment: Show your models code and forms

Answer (score 6):

Are you using `attr_accessible` anywhere in your model, to whitelist the fields that are allowed for mass assignment? If so, then you'll [also need to add](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for)

```
attr_accessible :address_attributes
```

to allow those attributes to be passed to `update_attributes`.

If you aren't already using `attr_accessible` (or it's not-recommended sister `attr_protected`) then *don't* add this line as it'll stop all of your ther attributes being saved.

Comment: Nope, no `attr_accessible` anywhere in my app.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar problem. In my case it was because of a "reject_if" clause in the accept_nested_attributes_for class method.

> accepts_nested_attributes_for :player, **:reject_if => proc {
>   |attributes| attributes['full_name'].blank?** }

By leaving an empty string in the player "full_name" attribute, Rails will not even try to update the attributes present in the nested form. In my case I realized I didn't need the reject_if clause so I fixed the problem by removing it.

Answer (score 1):

i created a gem called [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) which can help you with that.
It works with standard Rails forms, formtastic or simple-form.

The gem works with multiple nested levels. The readme on github should you get you started fairly easily. If you need more help, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having the same problem at updating, not at creating.
My class model is Lecture has_many widgets

```
class Lecture < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name , :order , :html, :widgets_attributes 
  has_many :widgets
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :widgets,  :allow_destroy => true
end

class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :lecture
    attr_accessible :width, :height, :xpos, :ypos, :source
end
```

The last line of the Widget class made all the difference.